# How to use EitherT to remove boilerplate with Future and Either

Tags: scala, scalaz

I need a combinator that works with `Future` and `\/` and I think that `EitherT` will help to remove boilerplate :

After some try, I've come up with

```
  type FutureEitherT[A] = EitherT[Future, String, A]

  def toKleisliEitherTFromDisjunction[A](f: Kleisli[Future, Context,String \/ A]) = Kleisli[FutureEitherT, Context, A] { ctx => EitherT(f(ctx)) }

  def h[A, B](f: Kleisli[Future, Context, String \/ A], g: A => Kleisli[Future, Context, String \/ B]) =
    for {
      a <- toKleisliEitherTFromDisjunction(f)
      b <- toKleisliEitherTFromDisjunction(g(a))
    } yield b
```

Comment: This isn't an answer, but if your `String` represents some kind of failure, why not just fail in the future?

Comment: @TravisBrown Can you explain further or provide a link ? I use a String to make a difference between a functional error and use Failure for technical error. Moreover, if I fail in the Future, I will need to convert the String to an Exception ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36568726/kleislifuture-context-to-kleislieithert-context)

```
  type FutureEitherT[A] = EitherT[Future, String, A]

  def h[A, B](f: Kleisli[Future, Context, String \/ A], g: A => Kleisli[Future, Context, String \/ B]) =
    for {
      a <- f.mapK[FutureEitherT, A](EitherT.eitherT)
      b <- g(a).mapK[FutureEitherT, B](EitherT.eitherT)
    } yield b
```